# Xamarin 'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am new to mobile dev, I followed a sample code in Xamarin site and when i run it it's giving me error

Error Name: `'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'actionBarSize'`

There are many other questions related to it and i tried there solution but they didn't work out for me

Bellow are the solutions link

1. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37239021/6856823)
2. [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36759115/6856823)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Android SDKs

Comment: try updating everything (xamarin.froms version, android sdk), then cleaning and building project

Comment: I want to run the code on xamarin emulator not on android emulator, but i couldn't find any xamarin emulator on my  `Debug Target`