# Xamarin.Forms Android project does not compile due to strange errors

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project that consists of a Portable Class Library (PCL), an iOS application and an Android application. When I build the solution, the PCL and the iOS projects build successfully, but the Android application doesn't build at all due to several strange errors as listed below:

> ```
> error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.
> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
> error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
> ```

What's even stranger is when I open NuGet Package Manager, I have a list of updates for the following components:

> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView

If I try to update any of the components, I get the following message:

> `Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 24.2.1' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.180'.`

I read somewhere that I should uninstall them completely because I won't have any need for them but if I try to uninstall any of the components, I get the following error:

> `Unable to uninstall 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.23.3.0' because 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.23.3.0' depends on it.`

Even the components that don't have **any** dependencies throw out a similar message if I try to uninstall them. I have searched online but I still can't seem to find a solution. So far, I have tried the following:

1. **Recreating the project completely.** This didn't help as the errors continued to appear
2. **Deleting the contents of** `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Xamarin\`**.** This solution didn't remove the errors at all.

Am I doing something wrong? All I'm doing is selecting the **Blank Xaml App (Xamarin.Forms Portable)** template in Visual Studio and naming my project. You can hardly make a mistake in that. As soon as I select Build, I get all the errors for the Android project. Is this a problem with Xamarin.Forms that needs to be addressed? Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching the Internet using different keywords, I solved this issue. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055924/failed-to-use-android-support-library-v4/36759115) post, the reason why some of the Android components were displaying those errors was because there was a corrupt ZIP download. This could happen because of:

- **Cancelling the build process.** If you cancel the build process for your Android application, any files being downloaded are also cancelled, resulting in corrupt files.
- **Any other interruptions.** Network errors or an unresponsive IDE could also result in this issue.

To solve this error, I would advise the following:

1. **Navigate to the following directory:**

   > `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin`
2. **Ensure that Visual Studio is completely closed.** This can be checked via Task Manager to ensure no other processes belonging to Visual Studio are running
3. **Delete the contents of the directory.** If any warning dialogs appear, select Skip and ensure that a folder called `zips` is deleted
4. **Open up your project and perform a cleanup.** You can then go ahead and build your project and Visual Studio will download the same files you deleted that aren't corrupted
5. **You should now have a working application!**

If the problem continues, please ensure you have followed these steps correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You should only update the Xamarin Forms package and leave the Xamarin.Android.* packages alone (the forms package will upgrade them for you).

Also those theme errors can be ignored, if your getting a compile error it is probably something else that is wrong.

Comment: Yeah. I finally realised that after a few days of struggling. I thought it was just a bug with Xamarin.Forms but I was wrong. The main problem was different and I outlined it in my answer above. Thanks for the info though.