# Xamarin Android CS0117 "Resource.Drawable does not contain a definition for XXX" during compile

Tags: android, xamarin, resources

When building a hybrid Xamarin Android app, we have a bizarre, intermittent issue.

The app is quite large and split into several components.

- App1

  - App1.Android
  - App1.iOS
- App2

  - App2.Android
  - App2.iOS
- Shared.Core
- Shared.Android
- Shared.iOS

App1.Android and App2.Android share Shared.Core and Shared.Android, App1.iOS and App2.iOS shared Shared.Core and Shared.iOS. It's Shared.Android (an Xamarin Android library) which is vexing me.

When attempting to compile, sometimes the build fails because it says that Resources.Drawable doesn't contain a reference to two specific items. These are seek.xml and seek_style.xml.

However IntelliSense sees the expected value and if I look into Resource.designer.cs the values are there and when F12ing to the source the two entities are listed.

The two files are in the Resource/drawable folder and as mentioned before can be F12ed to during normal IntelliSense operations.

I've tried several guides to resolve this issue, including the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36759115 but they only seem to provide temporary relief.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm tearing my hair out here.

Some screenshots:

1. File with reference (and working IntelliSense):
   [image: Base File]
2. Content of `Resources.Drawable`:
   [image: Resources.Drawable]
3. Compile time errors:
   [image: Compile time errors]
4. Files in Drawable folder (with properties):
   [image: seek.xml properties]
   [image: seek_style.xml properties]

Comment: Hi, "sometimes the build fails because it says that Resources" . Do you mean this build successfully sometimes?

Comment: Yes, it is occasionally possible to rebuild the solution using the steps in the answer I linked, but other times that also doesn't help.

Comment: Okey, It seems that the data is not synchronized. The *seek.xml and seek_style.xml* belong to which project, and do you always modify them before compling?

Comment: They belong to the `XXX.Shared.UI.Droid` project, the same as the `Resources.cs` file and the `SeekBarRenderer.cs` file which is referencing them. I've not modified them since the project was handed over to us end of last year.

Comment: It seems to be a old shared project, maybe there are some conflicts with the current version of Xamarin Froms and Visual Studio. I will continue to reasearch which reason should be.

Comment: I can confirm it's an "old style" MSBuild format (`<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`) project. I've tried a few times to migrate to the newer SDK style but the support for Xamarin is sketchy at best.

Comment: Maybe you could have a check with [Override ToolsVersion settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/overriding-toolsversion-settings?view=vs-2019), there are some ways to change the configurations.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what I'm supposed to do with this? Currently it builds using MSBuild v16, are you saying I should try to force it to use v15 instead?

Comment: Sorry, I mistaked you used the old version of MSBuild. If no, there will be no need to modify them.

Comment: I am running on MSBuild v16 on an up to date version of Visual Studio Professional 2019.

Comment: Hi, maybe you could have a try with cleaning the content of file [Resource.designer.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wZ8Y.png) , then rebuild the `XXX.Shared.UI.Droid` project.

Comment: When _emptying_ the Resources.designer.cs file, it is not regenerated on build, but is on rebuild. After rebuild `seek` and `seek_style` are both present.
After _deleting_ the Resourse.desginer.cs file, it is regenerated with the `seek` and `seek_style` properties included.

Still getting the two compile-time CS0117s though.

Comment: Okey, all the projects whether use the latest version of Visual Studio and Xamarin Froms?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest VS Professional 2019 version and Xamarin Forms is up to date. I noticed a change in behavior after deleting the Resources.designer.cs file, rebuilding and then "including" the newly generated version. It did build but I'm not sure if it's repeatable. Why aren't line breaks allowed in comments...

Comment: After rebuilding again the error reappears :(

Comment: Another interesting quirk: if Resources.designer.cs is not included in the project, when regenerated then the references to seek and seek_style are not present!

Comment: Hi, since the project structure is complex, and it seems no other people know the problem how to solve, then you could consider open a support ticket at http://support.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6 to get a more comprehensive support.

Comment: what are the contents of your xml files? does it contain key value pairs?

Comment: They are Android drawable/SVG style objects. I will reference one tomorrow for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Resources/drawable** folder − It stores all the images that you are going to use in your application.

**Resources/values** folder − It contains XML files to declare key-value pairs for strings (and other types) throughout an application. This is how localization for multiple languages is normally set up on Android.

You need to move the `seek.xml` and `seek_style.xml` files in `Resources/Values` folder and in properties window of xml files set:
[image]

Comment: I already tried this and it didn't help, normally the files located in Resources/drawable work as expected only during certain rebuild actions do they fail.